# Will the sleeping angler comeback if he died before moving in?

Tags: terraria-console

The sleeping angler died before he moved into a house. He just kept walking into the ocean right after i talked to him . And it said "john has left" in red letters does that mean hes gone for good or do i just have to find him again?

Answer (score 2):

He'll respawn again on his designated house or on the beach.

As for the death message, it is most likely due to the following reason as stated in the wiki:

> He also has a unique death message: Instead of "[Angler name] was slain..." the message reads "[Angler name] has left!" This is likely due to rating concerns, as depictions of children being killed tend to result in an Adults Only rating from the ESRB, which might have limited the game's distribution.